# Remove .php from action link in html

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove `.php` from the link in form's action attribute.

the link is:

`localhost/shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel.php/createExcel`.

I've tried using `.htaccess` from other questions, but I find only the way to remove .php at the very end of the link e.g

`localhost/shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel.php/createExcel.php`

to

`localhost/shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel.php/createExcel`.

I wonder how can I make the link to:

```
localhost/shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel/createExcel
```

If it isn't possible is there a better way so that I can hide the usage of `create_excel.php` from a user?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Not sure but try `RewriteRule ^shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel/createExcel$ shopproject/MassUpload/create_excel.php/createExcel [NC,L]
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you ONLY need it for this specific form...

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^create_excel/createExcel$ create_excel.php/createExcel.php
```

or if you have a lot of different forms using something like this...

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php/$2.php
```

Please note, you probably need to add the correct path that your live website uses.

I think something like this (if you added in proper paths) may be able to help you. I haven't done rewrites in a while, but this would say /anything/whatever is the same as /anything.php/whatever.php

so this would be like saying that /create_excel.php/createExcel.php can be accessed through create_excel/createExcel

If this doesn't work, or you can't create something similar in .htaccess, please try the following I suppose...

create_excel/createExcel/index.php
This would allow you to use site.com/create_excel/createExcel/ as a link, because index.php is automatically used (and not displayed in URL bar) when you set up a folder for this.

If you are using some sort of third party library or system, I highly recommend *not* creating a custom folder like this.

Comment: Ayyye, it works mate! Thank you very much for the answer. Have a nice day!